# In Excel, is there a way to be able to format the formula bar so that it is easier to read a long/multiple functions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I've tried searching for a solution to this problem, but all google results are fairly fruitless, at least with my search terms.

Is there some option/IDE/page that will automatically format a multi function excel formula to a more human readable layout? Either in Excel or outside?

Currently I have a several =if(and(if(and())if(and()))) statements that gumm up the legibility and was wondering if there is a solution for this.

The formula is as follows:

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),5,5),"")<>"-",IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),5,5),"")>0,INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),4,1)="rig"),IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),4,3),"")&" - "&IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),3,3),""),IF(AND(IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),5,5),"")="",INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),4,1)="rig"),"",IF(AND(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),4,1)="pickup",IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),6,3),"")<>"-"),IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),6,3),""),IF(AND(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),4,1)="pickup",IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),5,5),"")="-"),"",IF(1=1,IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),4,3),"")&" - "&IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),3,3),""),IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),4,3),"")&" - "&IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("Truck"&A72),3,3),""))))))
```

Looking at this it may be easier to refractor into VBA then continue along this path of If-Ands. But I don't anticipate many more, if any, conditions.

The gist is: The formula looks at cells to see if value has been applied to them, and will return the desired cells information based on that. Basically If a truck is a 'rig' and has weight, the Customer and Name will be returned, otherwise blanks are returned.

This particular formula is gathering information for a printable document that I can give to my loading crews in the evening, so they can pack it for delivery tomorrow. Im trying to automate my Job a bit. Because otherwise its all paper and pen here.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by more readable?  That is an opinion, to some the inline is the easiest.  Also if you showed what you are trying to do there may be a more simple formula that many nested IFs.

Comment: Please update your question with an actual example.

Comment: Inline works brilliantly for the most part, but this particular project I'm working on continues to grow so I need to keep checking for different variables in different cells. I'll update my post.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've updated my post. Thank you guys for looking into it.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I've updated my post. Thank you guys for looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your ?beautiful? formula an entered it into a cell.  Then I clicked in the formula bar and positioned the cursor before some of the `IFERROR`'s.  I then touched <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> + <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>.  I then increased the width of the formula bar.

This does not affect the functionality of the formula, but does affect the formatting in the formula bar:

[image]

Comment: Do you need to expand the formula bar in height first by clicking on the drop down arrow on the right side?

Comment: Completely answered! Thank you very much!

Comment: @ForwardEd  Thanks for the help!